# What are the other uses of Visual Memory Debugger, a given feature in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, objective-c-blocks, xcode8

Visual Memory Debugger can help me to find retain and release cycle or nasty/awesome blocks and closures that is not managing their memory well. I know I have to break memory management issues like __weak in objective c , may be owned self in swift.My question is what else it can be used for? I see a lot of visual clue in the diagram, so anyone would care to explain in detail other than memory management issues which could be debugged earlier, with line no in the code itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode Visual Memory Debugger helps you to find abandoned memory. It's one of simplest way to do it, inside IDE. Before release this feature you must open Instruments to check that. In my opinion it was uncomfortably. You can get more information about it in [Visual Debugging with Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/410/) video from last WWDC. Another way to do it is [FBMemoryProfiler](https://github.com/facebook/FBMemoryProfiler), read more about this useful framework in [this article](https://code.facebook.com/posts/583946315094347/automatic-memory-leak-detection-on-ios/) by Facebook.